# Verilog floating point to binary conversion

Tags: binary, floating-point, verilog, type-conversion

I am trying convert a signed floating number in Verilog to a signed 24 bit binary value. For example

```
-0.0065 would become: 24'b100000000110101001111110
0.0901 would become: 24'b000001011100010000110010
```

Is this correct?
Thank you

Comment: What is the floating point format?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the fractional decimal `0.0901` and converting to a fixed-point value with 2 integer bits and 22 fractional bits (24 bit total):

Ruby syntax used for the maths (you can cut and paste into irb (interactive ruby) a command line tool):

```
i = (0.0901 * 2**20) # 377906.7904
# truncat to integer value
i = i.to_i # 377906

# Convert to string using binary (base 2)
i.to_s(2) # "1011100010000110010"
```

To add the leading zeros (24 bit length), right justify and pad with 0's

```
i.to_s(2).rjust(24, '0') # "000001011100010000110010"

# Convert to Hex (base 16)
i.to_s(16) # "5c432"
```

Signed numbers are a bit more problematic, easiest way is to calculate positive value then perform twos complement :

```
(0.0065 * 2**22).to_i.to_s(2).rjust(24, '0')
=> "000000000110101001111110"
```

Twos complement

```
"000000000110101001111110"
"111111111001010110000001" # Ones complement (bit invert)
"111111111001010110000001" + 1 
"111111111001010110000010" #Twos complement
```

You had `24'b100000000110101001111110` which is just the positive number with the MSB set to `1` which is not how signed numbers normally work. The format you have used is Sign Magnitude, but you can not just feed that into a multiplier (as per your previous question).

NB: I have also skipped over the quantisation effect of converting to fixed point. Your coefficient when scaled by your fractional bit was 377906.7904. but we just take the integer part giving you an error of `0.7904` which will may effect your filter performance.