# Fixed and floating point in Verilog

Tags: floating-point, verilog, fixed-point

I come from VHDL back ground. And in VHDL, there is IEEE packages for doing fixed and floating point operations. They are not synthesisable sometimes, but are pretty helpful when comes to testing.

My question is, whether Verilog has a library for doing fixed and floating point operations? It doesnt matter if its not synthesisable.

Comment: You can always try to google it and find e.g. [this](http://www.eda.org/fphdl/old_index.html). But aren't real numbers good enough?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, See [Previous answer on handling fixed-point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28383767/97073). [also this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765266/97073) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28170918/97073).

Comment: I can use real numbers. But in vhdl, I normally use the fixed_pkg in testbench. to convert real values to and from fixed poiht values. But i guess in Verilog I have to write real to fixed functions on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Real operations are built into Verilog. See section **20.8.2 Real math functions** in the [IEEE 1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). You can also use the DPI to import many other math function from a standard C library. See https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/dpi/

For fixed point, you will need to shift you values manually.