# What is the most best way about fixed/floating point multiplication?

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

In generally, there are two methods as I know what multiplication fixed/floating point multiplication.
I'm Hardware Engineer like Verilog.

1.The one way 
[Verilog - Floating points multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758667/verilog-floating-points-multiplication)

2.The another way which is
to Shift left "<<"  then to shift right " >>"

I think above ways which is the results are all the same.
But I'm not sure, So I'm asking here what I want to know which way are esay to use and correct?

## Update1.

```
I think there are some way what multiplication in verilog.
```

1.way one.

```
What if I want to multipicate with 3.82 *2.581.
Then we can make integer above fractional numbers like this.
3.98*8  = 31.84.
What if we want only integer result then we could like this way to calculate .
3.98<<7 =3.98 * 2^7  = almost 509.
Then we can get 509 * 8 = 4072
Then we can 31 at 4072>>7.
```

2.way two.
    3.98  = almost 'b11_111110101...
    At here,  we can get to choice a suit depths for calculating multiplication.
    8 = 'b1000
    11_11111010  * 1000 = (4 int),(0 frac) * (2 int ),(8 frac)
    11 1111101000 = 8144
Then we get 8144*2^-8 = 31.8125

## update 2

I am confused  a multiplication between [how can I apply fixed fraction to the integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383416/how-can-i-apply-fixed-fraction-to-the-integer) and [Verilog - Floating points multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758667/verilog-floating-points-multiplication)

Which one is better way?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. are you asking how to do fractional and looking for fixed point vs floating point or how to do fixed point multiplication. your link 1 just describes how to interpret the result of `*`, `<<` then`>>`  I think is discussing multiplier implementation, not the interpretation of fixed point data.

Comment: @Morgan . I'm asking about the which one multiplication method is better at between first and second. I think both of all above are about multiplication at the fixed point. Am I missing ?

Comment: Better how? Easy to implement, maintain, faster or lower power. Shift add can be split over multiple cycles, so data rates compared to clock rate is also a consideration.

Comment: @Morgan but I think. Even shift and add can be split over multiple cycle,  but I think those are better than "*" regarding of easy and maintanance , doesn't it? Sometime designware performance are very good, nowdays it just used directly "*"  in verilog.

Comment: What is simpler than a single line of code. Mul = a*b; and it allows tools to optimise timing easier than a specific implementation.

Comment: @Morgan BTW,  if we would calculate the floating point multiplication then should we have to calculate as assume that is fixed point?

Comment: Sorry not sure I followed that, but `*` is not synthesisable for floating point operations only for integer or fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do fixed-point arithmetic is to use a fixed-point library that has (hopefully) been carefully written and debugged. You're using Verilog, so just search for 'verilog fixed point library' in Google. You'll find this

http://opencores.org/project,verilog_fixed_point_math_library

and others. I am not recommending this particular one because I have not used it, but you can see that it has been used by many people.