# what is the difference between " CSD multiplication" "verilog multiplication"?

Tags: verilog

I have seen 2 posting at here [Verilog - Floating points multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758667/verilog-floating-points-multiplication)

and
[how can I apply fixed fraction to the integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383416/how-can-i-apply-fixed-fraction-to-the-integer)

As you can se,  those are all regarding of verilog fraction multiplication.
But I can confused that Mogan's answer of this.

```
reg [7:0] a = 0010_1000; reg [7:0] b = 0010_1000;
```

How can he got this binary? Is this CSD terms?

## Update

I know well interger * CSD term. It will converted like this figure( integer >>2)+(integer>> 5)..
But I want to kow CSD term * CSD term.

What about this?

```
wire [11:0] y;
wire [11:0] x;
wire [11:0] z;
y= {3.1, 10'b0}
x= {2.5, 10'b0}
z= y*x
z = z >> 10;
```

Now I think this is little a bit cost than your way.
you can use just just one multiplication.
But my method is need shifter to right.

Comment: [Looking at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765266/97073) where the question talks about multiplying 2.5 * 2.5. The answer describes how to interpret an 8 bit number comprised of 4 integer bits and 4 fractional bits. using `_` as a binary point marker `0010_1000` represents 2.5. CSD would contain negative terms denoted by 1 BAR (T) this is just a binary word with 4 fractional places. If you could elaborate on which part your stuck I can try explain it better.

Comment: @Morgan  My stuck point is that what if I want to multiplication calculate fraction number like 2.5 x 2.5 then how can I use CSD term in verilog? For example 2.5 is  0010_0111 and this is able to convert CSD 0010_100T. As you already know the T is just expression, it does not use in verilog. So my question is how to we apply CSD term numbers into verilog multiplication? CSD term x CSD term.

Comment: What do you mean by CSD term, the full CSD number  (`0010_100T`) or just a single part of it (`T`, `-2^4`)?

Comment: @Morgan I meant full numver T.  <=Here is used T.   What if you have to multiplication by using two CSD number,  then how do you calculate? Actually it does not matter single or full. Does'n it? For example 0010_100T *  0010_100T

Comment: How are you representing `0010_100T` in verilog. I am not aware of why you would end up with two CSD formats for multiplication. as the CSD conversion of a number is designed to make multiplication easy.

Comment: @Morgan sir then How do yo calculate 3.1x2.5?

Comment: How do you represent 3.1 ? How many fractional bits are you wanting to use?

Comment: @Morgan sir  i think integer 4bits anf fraction bits 4bit i think.

Answer (score 1):

To answer a question in a comment How to multiply 3.1*2.4 in Signed 4 int 4 frac wordlength.

```
3.1 => 0011_0001 (actually 3.0625) .1 is very difficult to represent in fixed point.
2.5 => 0010_1000
```

[EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/BDx):

```
reg signed [15:0] mul;
initial begin
  mul = 8'sb0011_0001 * 8'sb0010_1000;
  $display("mul = %16b", mul);
end
//mul = 0000011110101000
```

Break down of result:

```
     2^ 76543210 -1-2-3-4-5
  mul = 00000111_ 1 0 1 0 1 000
2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-3 2^-5
  4 +   2 +   1 + 0.5 +0.125 + 0.03125
              =======
              7.65625
```

On a normal calculator:

```
3.0625 * 2.5 => 7.65625
```

The rounding from 3.1 to 3.0625 caused this error `3.1*2.5 => 7.75`, quantisation error of 0.09375.

Comment: I have got 2 question 1.Would you let me know how to make 3.1 => 0011_0001 (actually 3.0625) .1 is very difficult to represent in fixed point.
2.5 => 0010_1000 ?

Comment: 2.  you use this way to calculate multiplication of what input [9:0] a,

wire [19:0] a_frac = { a, 10'b0};
Remember Verilog thinks this is an integer but we have have to interpret the number differently.

wire [19:0] y = (a_frac>>1) - (a_frac>>5) - (a_frac>>7) + (a_frac>>10);  My question is which one is better way ?

Comment: are you asking how to get from 3.1 to `0011_0001`? are you comfortable with the fact that `0011_0001` represents 3.0625?

Comment: @bural if both are functionally equivalent, how do you define better? Have you compared synthesis results of both, I recommend you do.

Comment: Sir, yes I'm asking about  how to get from 3.1 to 0011_0001. are you applying CSD in it already? My question if you yes, How can I treat T?

Comment: There is no -1 implied (`T`) in so no it is not CSD, just regular twos complement. You could do  `010T_0001` that would be a CSD form.

Comment: 3.1 with 4 fractional bits, `3.1 * 2^4 =  49.6`. The 0.6 is truncated as we can only represent integers. google 49 in binary `0b110001`. are you comfortable with this translation from fractional to fixed point?

Comment: Yes sir Actually  the number of less than one is ignored in real image color domain