# Exponential decay in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm new to Verilog and I need a little help here. 
I have a register array `reg [32-1:0] out` which represents a signed integer.
A smaller array holds a number between 0 and 1000 `reg [14-1:0] d`. I would like to do something like this (damping out on every clock cycle):

```
always @(posedge clk_i) begin
    out <= $signed(out) * $unsigned(d)/1000;
end
```

I heared that using / is bad practice for synthesizable code. Can anyone show me how to implement such an exponential decay?

EDIT:
I changed dividing by 1000 to dividing by 1024, because it's much easier to handle. My code looks now like this:

```
reg [32-1:0] out;
reg [32-1:0] in;
reg [42-1:0] tmp;
reg [14-1:0] d;
always @(posedge clk_i) begin
    tmp = {in,10'd0};
    if(tmp[41]==1) begin
      tmp = $signed(tmp) * -1;
      tmp = $signed(tmp) >> 10;
      tmp = $signed(tmp) * $unsigned(d);
      tmp = $signed(tmp) * -1;
    end
    else begin
      tmp = $signed(tmp) >> 10;
      tmp = $signed(tmp) * $unsigned(d);
    end
    out <= tmp[42-1:10];
 end
```

The code works well in simulation but on the fpga it seems like in is multiplied by zero (out is zero)? Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Consider D to be fixed-point instead of an integer. It can now store fractional information. Store the new d as 'old d/1000' and your problem is just multiplication, no division.

Comment: [Verilog: fixed-point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28383767/97073)

Comment: I changed my code. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Signed number should use `>>>` to sign extend. Not sure why you need to do the `* -1` maybe the `>>>` will solve the issue. Also consider multiplying before shifting to maintain better precision.

Also doing :

```
tmp = {in,10'd0};
tmp = $signed(tmp) >> 10;
```

does not make too much sense you have padded the LSBs with 0's then shift the zeros out.

Sign extending (equivalent to `>>>`) this could be MSB replicated 10 times:

```
tmp = { {10{in[32-1]}}, in};
```

I would avoid reusing variables like `tmp` and use named and sized variables for each section, this will not effect the synthesised size.

Comment: The problem was somewhere else. But thanks anyways, I guess your code is better practice