# Verilog code to compute cosx using Taylor series approximation

Tags: verilog, taylor-series, digital-design

I'm trying to implement COS X function in Verilog using Taylor series. The problem statement presented to me is as below

**"Write a Verilog code to compute cosX  using Taylor series approximation. Please attach the source and test bench code of the 8-bit outputs in signed decimal radix format for X = 0° to 360° at the increment of 10° "**

I need to understand a couple of things before i proceed. **Please correct me if i am wrong someplace**

**Resolution calculation :** 10° increments to cover 0° to 360° => 36 positions

36 in decimal can be represented by 6 bits. Since we can use 6 bits, the resolution is slightly better by using 64 words. The 64 words represent 0° to 360°   hence each word represents a resolution of 5.625° ie all values of Cos from 0° to 360° in increments of 5.625°. **Thus resolution is 5.625°**

**Taylor series calculation**
Taylor series for cos is given by   [Cos x approximation by Taylor series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya0cc.png)

```
      COS X  =  1  −  (X^2/2!)  +  (X^4/4!)  − (X^6/6!) .....   (using only 3~4 terms)
```

**I have a couple of queries**

1) While it is easy to generate X*X (X square) or X cube terms using a multiplier, i am not sure how to deal with the extra bits generated during calculation of X square or X cube terms . ***Output is 8 bits only***

eg    X=6 bits ;                  X square =12 bits ;           X cube = 18 bits.

Do i generate them anyways and later ignore them by considering just the MSB 8 bits of the entire result ? ... such a cos wave would suck right ?

2) I am not sure how to handle the +1 addition at start of Taylor series ...COS X  =  **1** −  (X^2/2!)  +  (X^4/4!) .... Do i add binary 1 directly or do i have to scale the 1 as 2^8 = 255 or 2^6 = 64  since i am using **6 bits at input** and **8 bits at output** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this number series normally gives a number in the range +1 to -1. SO you have to decide how you are going to use your 8 bits.

I think a signed number with 1 integer bit and 7 fractional bits, you will not be able to represent 1, but very close.

I have a previous answer explaining [how to use fixed-point with verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170918/97073).  Once your comfortable with that you need to look at [how bit growth occurs during multiply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765266/97073).

Just because you are outputting 1 bit int, 7 bit frac internally you could (should) use more to compute the answer.

With 7 fractional bits a 1 integer would look like `9'b0_1_0000000` or `1*2**7`.